# print the smallest subarray with sum greater than or equal target

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic-programming

````
```import sys
 
# Function to find the smallest subarray
# with sum greater than or equal target
def minlt(arr, target, n):
 
    # DP table to store the
    # computed subproblems
    dp = [[-1 for _ in range(target + 1)]\
    for _ in range(len(arr)+1)]
    #pf = [-1 for _ in range(len(arr)+1)]
     
    for i in range(len(arr)+1):
         
        # Initialize first
        # column with 0
        dp[i][0] = 0
         
    for j in range(target + 1):
 
        # Initialize first
        # row with 0
        dp[0][j] = sys.maxsize
 
    for i in range(1, len(arr)+1):
        for j in range(1, target + 1):
 
            # Check for invalid condition
            if arr[i-1] > j:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j]
 
            else:
                # Fill up the dp table
                #if dp[i-1][j] == 1 or (1 + dp[i][j-arr[i-1]]) == sys.maxsize:
                dp[i][j] = min(dp[i-1][j], \
                1 + dp[i][j-arr[i-1]])

                 
    return dp[-1][-1]
 
    # Print the minimum length
    if dp[-1][-1] == sys.maxsize:
        return(-1)
    else:
        return dp[-1][-1]
 
# Driver Code
arr = [10,9,2,1]
target = 11
n = len(arr)
 
print(minlt(arr, target, n))
````

can anyone make change to this program such that it will print the smallest subarray not the length
This code returns only length of smallest subarray whose sum is greater or equal to given target
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Given your identified input, what are you defining as possible subarrays?  As I interpret a subarray, the subarrays with sum >= to target include:  [10,9,2,1], [10, 9,2], [10,9], [9,2,1], and [9,2] and the smallest subarray >= target would be [9,2].   Is this correct?  The reason I ask is I don't understand the rationale for use of sys.maxsize.

Comment: Yes, sys.maxsize is INT_MAX in c++

Comment: In C++ INT_MAX specifies an integer variable that equates to the max Integer limit. of the system on which the application is running.  In Python sys.max_size maxsize is quite a bit different.  The sys module fetches the largest value a variable of data type Py_ssize_t can store. It is essentially the Python platform’s word size.  What you are looking for is int(math.inf).  Although in your case, the value returned by sys.maxsize will also do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how In would do what you want.

```
#First the function definition
def minlt(arr, target):
    rslt = (None, None, None) #tuple containing the (subarray_sum, subarray_start, sub_array_length)
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        for k in range(i+1, len(arr)):
            arsm = sum(arr[i:k])
            if arsm >= target:
                if rslt[0] == None or rslt[2] > k-i+1 or (rslt[2] == k-i+1 and rslt[0] > arsm):
                    rslt = (arsm, i, k-i+1)
    return arr[rslt[1]:rslt[2]]
```

Then the call setup:

```
arr = [10,9,2,1]
target = 11
minlt(arr, target)
```

Yielding:

```
[9, 2]
```